# Boolean expression to a truth table

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How do I fill a truth table from the following expression? I can't decide whether it is SOP or POS.

```
Y=(A+B)C+AB`+(A+C)C`+(`AB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoP or PoS doesn't matter when building a truth table, you just list out the 8 possible inputs and then derive the possible outputs.

If A B and C are all false what is the value of Y?

If only C is true what is the value of Y?

And so on.